# jetty-maven-plugin and MultiPart requests

Tags: maven, jetty, multipart

I'm trying to set up jetty-maven-plugin to run my spring project, which currently runs ok on tomcat7. The problem im having is when submitting a multipart form I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet
```

Ive hunted all over the jetty docs, and can find how to configure it using java, but how to I get the maven plugin launched version to handle multipart?

My plugin config is currently:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.11.v20130520</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/servlet</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I found this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395000 and then downgraded to 8.1.7 and it started to work fine. Strange thing is I do have a:

```
<multipart-config>
```

section in my servlet config:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <!-- Needed for processing multipart forms ahead of the HiddenHttpMethodFilter -->
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
             <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
         <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold> <!-- 1MB -->
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

So this issue shouldn't apply here

Cheers
NFV